# Replacing whole XML tree in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

How to replace a whole XML tree?
Let's say I have a file that looks like:

```
<root>
  <folder>
    <elem1>'something here'</elem1>
    <elem2>'more stuff here'</elem2>   
    <elem3>
       <sub1>'something else here'</sub1>
       <sub2>'blablabla'</sub2>
    </elem3>
    <elem4>'even more stuff here with subelements too'</elem4> 
  </folder>
</root>
```

And I also have another xml file that would be an alternative for `elem3` that looks like:

```
    <NewElem>
       <Difsub1>'something else here, but different'</Difsub1>
       <Difsub2>'all sorts of different blablabla'</Difsub2>
    </NewElem>
```

What I need is to replace `elem3` with `NewElem`, that results in:

```
<root>
  <folder>
    <elem1>'something here'</elem1>
    <elem2>'more stuff here'</elem2>   
    <NewElem>
       <Difsub1>'something else here, but different'</Difsub1>
       <Difsub2>'all sorts of different blablabla'</Difsub2>
    </NewElem>
    <elem4>'even more stuff here with subelements too'</elem4>  
  </folder>
</root>
```

I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree` and tried to `append` it but I end up getting the `NewElem` in the end, after `</folder>`. I could not remove the `elem3` of the updated xml file.

**I tried to append it using this:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('base.xml')
baseroot = tree.getroot()
tree2 = ET.parse('new.xml')
newroot = tree2.getroot()

old_element = baseroot.findall('.//elem3')
baseroot.append(newroot)
baseroot.remove(old_element)
```

With that the `NewElem` gets appended after folder, and I need in the same place where `elem3` was, or at least inside `<folder>`
Also, when removing I get an error:
`TypeError: remove() argument must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not list`
If I change to

```
old_element = baseroot.find('.//elem3')
baseroot.append(newroot)
baseroot.remove(old_element)
```

I get very similar error: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Comment: ...if `.append()` does not do what you want, surely there are other options to try [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file)? How to remove elements is explained there as well.

Comment: I am using the provided documentation, but still my noob level maybe is in the way... when trying to remove I get an error complaining that it is not a list, and when it is python complains it is not a elementtree thing... :(

Comment: That's why you need to *show your code* in your question. Nobody can see what you are doing (or doing wrong) when you don't show any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thank you @egur and @Henrik for guiding, specially pointing to a different library. I am using lxml ([and this documentation](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#parsing-from-strings-and-files)) and so I could do what I wanted using the following code:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('base.xml')
new = etree.tostring(etree.parse('new.xml')) # parsing to a string so it can be appended later

for elem in tree.xpath(".//elem3"): # finds the parent where the element to be replaced are
    elem.getparent().append(etree.fromstring(new)) #append in the end of parent, the fromstring() is because append don't like elementTree
    elem.getparent().remove(elem)

print(etree.tostring(tree, encoding="utf-8").decode('utf-8'))
```

The above code produces the following:

```
<root>
  <folder>
    <elem1>'something here'</elem1>
    <elem2>'more stuff here'</elem2>   
    <elem4>'even more stuff here with subelements too'</elem4> 
  <NewElem>
       <Difsub1>'something else here, but different'</Difsub1>
       <Difsub2>'all sorts of different blablabla'</Difsub2>
    </NewElem></folder>
</root>
```

Note that the `NewElem` is after `elem4`, not exactly where `elem3` was, but within `folder` so I think that solves what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The below is using the `lxml` package, a superior XML package to `ElementTree`.
You can find the index of the node you'd like to replace using the parent element's `index(element)` method.

Once you got that, you can use `insert(index, element)` from the parent and insert the new node in the position of the old.

The next thing is delete the old node via the `remove(element)` method

Example 'p' is the parent element, `a` is the child node of `p` to be replaced and `b` is the new child node:

```
p.insert(p.index(a), b) # insert b before a
p.remove(a)
```

With `ElementTree`, you'll need to find the index of the old element first:

```
p = et.Element('parent') # parent node
a = et.Element('child1') # this is the child node to be replaced
b = et.Element('child2') # this is the new child node
p.append(a) 
index = list(p).index(a)
p[index] = b
```

Comment: following what you said `parent.index('elem3')` gives me `AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'index'` could you elaborate a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: Added code that better suits your question. I advise you to try lxml. Additional functions on top of the ElementTree API and it's much faster.

Comment: Could not make it work. `from lxml import etree` then `tree = etree.parse('base.xml')` when trying `tree.index('elem3')` it gives me `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'index'` . I am using [this lxml documentation](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#parsing-from-strings-and-files)

Comment: @Jonathan, you need to add this line to get the root XML element object of the tree: `tree.getroot()`. The `index` function is part of the XML element object and `tree` is not such an object.

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on using 'ElementTree', first you should realize that erase only works on the node that directly contain the node you want to remove.

so while searching for it like this

```
old_element = baseroot.find('.//elem3')
```

is fine, you cannot remove it from the baseroot, you need to get the  it resides in, and remove it from there. The easiest must be to get it's parent

```
old_element_parent = xml.find('.//elem3/..')
old_element_parent.remove(old_element )
```

adding a new element can be done with SubElement

```
a = ET.SubElement(old_element_parent, 'NewElement')
```

Comment: I don't insist on using 'ElementTree', it happens to be the one that is/was working so far. I am happy to change for something better. Regarding the answer, this: `old_element_parent = xml.find('.//elem3/..')
old_element_parent.remove(old_element )`  gives me the following error: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Comment: This is surprising, as I tested it in python 3.8.1, glad you found a better solution though